# Implement an Interface for multiple classes in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I have a large number of classes and an interface. All I want to do it select all of the classes and add "implements  " to each of them without having to do it manually. Is this possible?

that is ALL I want to do, simply add the implementation

Comment: Type " implements MyInterface" into notepad; select the string, and press Ctrl-C. Position cursor after the name of your class in the editor, and press Ctrl-V. Repeat for the remaining classes. :):):):)

Comment: yeah, that would be manually... I appreciate the humor though

Comment: You would also need to implement the interface's methods in all the classes (if the interface contains at least one). This kind of refactoring is so rare that I doubt there are any special tools for it.

Comment: there is no  method, it is a blank interface... How is this rare?
There is a way to extract and configure already implemented interfaces but there is actually no way to simply implement one to multiple classes? That seems ridiculous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use search and Replace all feature  for this project in eclipse.

EDIT
A very basic replace is like this
search (ctrl+H and select File Search make sure regex is checked. Also you can search only this project with .java files) for all occurrence of the following regex
`(public class+ \w+\s+)`
Click replace button (shown in File Search or in search results) and enter the following string to replace
`$1 implements myinterface`
Basically The  regex `(public class+ \w+\s+)` value is captured in `$1`. this might not work in cases where there are inner classes etc
You might need to import this interface to prevent any compiler errors.(may be one more regex :)

Note: make sure you use the 'preview' option before you replace all occurrence in 'Replace text matches window'

Answer (score 0):

Select the class in Eclipse, right click on it and go to Properties.

Comment: this did not give me any such option

Comment: @srikanth could you explain a little bit in details..!!

Comment: provided sample regex in the answer

Comment: @srikanthyaradla cool dude...!! have to find for inner classes also..!!